# Cannot Play After Rename File - TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, gnome-terminal, os.system

I have an error when after rename files and want to access it using the module `os.system`. namely the script `os.system('mpg321' + ren)`.

I've done `os.chdir` on the path.
but still it is still not working.

Here I use the power `mpg321` for player.
and deliberately did not use the module as `pymedia` or other.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Play_Next.py", line 52, in <module>
    os.system('mpg321 ' + ren)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

And this my complete script..

```
import os, time

mypath = 'Mymusic'
filenames = os.listdir(mypath)
len_file = len(filenames)

inp = input('Enter Start Playlist (ex: 2): ')

less = len_file - inp
indexed = filenames[less]

x = os.listdir(mypath)
#pindah_dir = os.chdir(mypath)
#pindah_dir

if x[inp] in x:
    print ' [+] Mp3 File indexed: ', indexed
    print ' ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ '
    os.chdir(mypath)
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            inp += 1
            print x[inp]
            inden = x[inp]
            rename1 = inden.replace(' ','').replace('-','').replace('(','').replace(')', '').replace("'", '')
            ren = os.rename(inden, rename1)

            play_next = os.system('mpg321 ' + ren)
            play_next

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "\n\tThankyou.."
            break

        except IndexError:
            print "Repeat from the beginning.."
            inp = 0
            inp += 1
            print x[inp]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that `os.rename` don't return the new file's path like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.rename('/Users/zookeep/Desktop/test.py', '/Users/zookeep/Desktop/ok.py')
None
```

You can use `os.path.join` to get the rename file' name:

```
>>> os.path.join('/Users/zookeep/Desktop/test.py', 'ok.py')
'/Users/zookeep/Desktop/test.py/ok.py'
```

So change your code like:

```
try:
  os.rename(inden, rename1)
  ren = os.path.join(inden, rename1)
  play_next = os.system('mpg321 ' + ren)
except Exception, error:
  print error
```

May helps.

Comment: I've successfully for rename file.. but my problem is can't access file after rename file..